# How to change screen color with interrupts in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I need a proc that change the color of the screen every few time and I have a direction,

```
proc ColorPrint
mov AX,1003h 
mov BL,01h
INT 10h 
ret
endp ColorPrint
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is your _exact_ question?

Comment: i have a program that print a note to the user and i wand at the end to change the color of the text..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? Did you google this? I tried the search 'assembly change color' and got some seemingly useful hits. Please go through the new user tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour), how to ask a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the help section in general before asking.

Comment: `mov AX,1003h` is for "Toggle blink/intensity" (`int 10h` function `10h` subfunction `03h`).

Comment: i did googled it and non of the results helped me

Comment: How do you print that note? Either by direct video memory access or by BIOS interrupt services, you have to specify the attribute (i.e. the color), see for example [this](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0099.htm). If you use an high level function of a runtime/framework tell us what it is.